# Convert csv file to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a csv to dictionary with the following structure:

```
{
"0": {"val1": 1, "val2": 2, "val3": 3, ..., "valn": n},
"1": {"val1": 45, "val2": 7, "val3": None, ..., "valn": 68},
}
```

Where as val1, val2 and so on are the header names of the columns and "0" and "1" are the number of rows.

I've tried:

```
dicti = { i : reader[i] for i in range(0, len(reader) ) }
```

But I got the following result:

```
{
 1: ['value1','value2'],
 2: ['value_x', 'value_y']
  ...
}
```

and

```
import pandas as pd
dicti = pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0, squeeze=True, header=0).to_dict()
```

But I do not get to achieve the result I want.

I appreciate any further clarification. 
Thank you

**CSV content is like this:**

```
color,property,type,id
red,house,building,02 

{
"0": {"color": "red", "property": "house", "type": "building", ..., "valn": n},
"1": {"color": "blue", "property": "farm", "type": "area", ..., "valn": n},
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get the headers is using [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). Also, use `enumerate` for a more Pythonic code to get the index of a row.

```
import csv

with open('file') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    d = {row_index : row for row_index , row in enumerate(reader)}
```

With this CSV

```
h1,h2,h3
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

You get this for `d`:

```
{0: OrderedDict([('h1', 'a'), ('h2', 'b'), ('h3', 'c')]),
 1: OrderedDict([('h1', 'd'), ('h2', 'e'), ('h3', 'f')])}
```

If you insist on having "regular" dictionaries as the values (I don't see any reason why though) you can use `d = {row_index : dict(row) for row_index , row in enumerate(reader)}` instead.

Comment: Thank you but with this solution I don't get the format I want, which should be like the first snippet in my question

Comment: @js352  Why do you care? It is just the string representation of `OrderedDict`. You can still very easily access it as a ""normal"" dictionary, ie `d[0]['h1']`. If you are referring to the fact that in your example the row indexes are strings, simply do `str(row_index)` but I don't see any benefit in doing so. Indexes are integers pretty much by definition

Comment: @js352 Either way, if you insist, you can use `d = {row_index : dict(row) for row_index , row in enumerate(reader)}` instead

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. Now I'm trying to figure out how to do this without using csv.DictReader() or the like. I mean, creating myself the dictionary and ordering keys and values from the scratch.  Using `d = {row_index : row for row_index , row in enumerate(line)}` gets me a dictionary with all the values but without keys as stated in the question. What would be the best way in doing this?

Answer (score -2):

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('filename.csv', 'r'))
d = {}
for row in reader:
   k, v = row
   d[k] = v
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: That's not even close to the output OP wants, and it also only works if every row has exactly 2 elements (and still provides the wrong output)